# First coordinate of a randomly chosen point in an Euclidean ball.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The first coordinate of a point that is chosen at random in the Euclidean ball of radius $\sqrt{3} $ according to the uniform distribution. Calculate the distribution function, mean and variance of $x_{1}$.

**My approach:**

I think that $x_{1}$ most be in $[-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}]$. If that is the case I have the following function:
\begin{align*}
F_{x_{1}}=P[x_{1}\leq y] = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \text{if}\ \  y<-\sqrt{3}\\[2em]
1 & \text{if}\ \  y<\sqrt{3}\\
? & \text{if}\ \  -\sqrt{3}<y<\sqrt{3}
\end{array} \right.\text{for every}\ y\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

How do I find the last part of the preceding function?. I know I must find an integral. Assuming I have X, Y and Z axes, should I do a triple integral considering the $dxdydz$?

Comment: You need to find the volume of a segment of the ball cut out by a plane. This is a solid of revolution, and only a single integration is needed.